# ElasticSearch search_analyzer applied but no result returned

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, mapping, query-analyzer

I have a query that should search for lowercase terms.

Actually I just had a *index_analyzer* with a lowercase filter, but I wanted to add also a *search_analyzer* so I could do case-insensitive searches.

```
"analysis": {
    "analyzer" : {
        "DefaultAnalyzer": {
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "whitespace",
            "filter": [
                "lowercase"
            ],
            "char_filter": ["punctuation"]
        },
        "MyAnalyzer": {
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "first_letter",
            "filter": [
                "lowercase"
            ]
        },
```

So I just thought to add the same analyzer as *search_analyzer* into the mapping

```
"index_analyzer": "DefaultAnalyzer",
"search_analyzer": "DefaultAnalyzer",
"dynamic" : false,
"_source": { "enabled": true },
"properties" : {
    "name": {
        "type": "multi_field",
        "fields": {
            "name": {
                "type": "string",
                "store": true
            },
            "startletter": {
                "type": "string",
                "index_analyzer": "MyAnalyzer",
                "search_analyzer": "MyAnalyzer",
                "store": true
            }
        }
    },
```

Doing like that, if I manually query Elastic Search with

```
curl -XGET host:9200/my-index/_analyze -d 'Test'
```

I see that the query term is correctly lowercased

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "test",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 4,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

But executing from the code

- if I use an uppercase search term ES returns zero hits (even if we saw that the *search_analyzer* is applied)
- if I use a lowercase search term ES returns me the right number of result hits (hundreds)

**While I would like to have the same result independently from the case.**

In the code I'm just creating a query with a term filter, that is like that

```
{
  "filter": {
    "term": {
      "name.startletter": "O"
    }
  },
  "size": 10000,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

What I'm doing wrong? Why am I not getting any result?

Comment: I don't get the reason for the downvoting.
Is it a stupid question, or did I do something wrong?...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a Term Filter. A Term Filter does not analyze the text being used:

> **Term Filter**
>
> Filters documents that have fields that contain a term (not analyzed).
>   Similar to term query, except that it acts as a filter.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-filter.html

Since it does not analyze, it does not use the analyzer that you have defined.

You generally want to use Term filters and queries with fields that are not analyzed. Change your filter type to something that will analyze during the query.

Comment: You are right!
What kind of filter could I use as alternative, for doing the same thing? (_searching by lowercased starting letter_)
I'm trying with a Bool filter, but I end in putting anyway a Term filter into it.
A Match_all filter? Another one?

Comment: I actually switched to a Query filter, using the same _{"term": {"name.startletter": "O"}}_ into a query instead that directly in the filter. Is it a good solution in you opinion? Won't I loose in performance using a query (even if inside a filter)?

Comment: I finally stayed for this solution with Query Filter. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you are using MyAnalyzer to get start letter of indexed, Your analyzer don't work in that way. I've dome some test, and finally come up with solution.

First, create index and mapping (+ settings)

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/t1" -d'
{
   "settings": {
      "index": {
         "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
               "DefaultAnalyzer": {
                  "type": "custom",
                  "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                  "filter": [
                     "lowercase"
                  ]
               },
               "MyAnalyzer": {
                  "type": "custom",
                  "tokenizer": "token_letter",
                  "filter": [
                     "one_token","lowercase"
                  ]
               }
            },
            "tokenizer": {
               "token_letter": {
                  "type": "edgeNGram",
                  "min_gram": "1",
                  "max_gram": "1",
                  "token_chars": [
                     "letter",
                     "digit"
                  ]
               }
            },
            "filter": {
               "one_token": {
                  "type": "limit",
                  "max_token_count": 1
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings": {
      "t2": {
         "index_analyzer": "DefaultAnalyzer",
         "search_analyzer": "DefaultAnalyzer",
         "dynamic": false,
         "_source": {
            "enabled": true
         },
         "properties": {
            "name": {
               "type": "multi_field",
               "fields": {
                  "name": {
                     "type": "string",
                     "store": true
                  },
                  "startletter": {
                     "type": "string",
                     "index_analyzer": "MyAnalyzer",
                     "search_analyzer": "simple",
                     "store": true
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

And, now write a data.

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/t1/t2/1" -d'
{
    "name" :"Oliver Khan"
}'
```

Now, Here is fun part, Just a query and facet to see what is indexed.

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/t1/t2/_search" -d'
{
  "filter": {
    "term": {
      "name.startletter": "O"
    }
  },
  "size": 10000,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "facets": {
     "tf": {
        "terms": {
           "field": "name.startletter",
           "size": 10
        }
     }
  }
}'
```

This gives me analyzed text, as facet output, so I can check if analyzer is working. 
Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thank you for your effort! By the way I would like to maintain the same analyzer as search_analyzer (if in the future the analysers will change I want the changes to be reflected either in the indexing and the searching).

Comment: And the real problem is I'm using the wrong type of filter (that doesn't work with analyzed data), as @JohnPetrone writes. Actually I need to know what kind of filter to use instead...